# Skip or Automatically Answers questions after opening jar file using .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, jar

When i run a jar file using this command  in cmd.

```
  java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken
```

it asks for userName and Password **(Hidden Fields)** and then ask for Y/N

I want to automatically answer these question in console.

I created a batch file using different technique but none of them worked
forexample i wrote userName and password using | and & secondly i added /Q to enforce it, not to ask for userName /Password and conformation.

*None of techniques worked.*

My bat file looks like this

```
java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken
& userName123
& Password123
& y

pause
```

**Then**

I realized it is impossible directly to do it with bat file.
so i have created a small java program that is build and executed by bat file 
like this.

```
javac program.java
java program
pause
```

**Question:** 
I want to write a program that automatically writes userName "abc" and then password "123" and then "Y";

Currently My program looks like this.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.lang.Process;

class program{
public static void main(String[] args){

try{
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken");
    proc.waitFor();
    InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();

    byte b[]=new byte[in.available()];
    in.read(b,0,b.length);
    System.out.println(new String(b));

}catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex);
}
   }
}
```

and I am confused about how to move on using Output Stream. Please help

Edited

Using this in bat file

```
echo username.dk pas01% y& java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken 
pause
pause
pause
```

i got
[image]

Comment: rather try like `echo user password y| java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken`

Comment: wrote it like this but 
       echo "tuser" "abc01%"
       |java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken
       pause
but cmd splashes and disapears @npocmaka

Comment: even without  quotation marks

Comment: so i wrote pause 3 times and then it stops. I can only see null in response @npocmaka

Comment: then try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c echo user pass y| java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken");`

Comment: @npocmaka still returning null

Answer (score 0):

Place in a file `param.txt`:

```
yuserName123
yPassword123
y
```

Three lines, last also with a newline.

```
java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken <param.txt
```

Now the batch file delivers the file as System.in.

Comment: after i ran the batch file, it wrote null in param.txt

Comment: `type param.txt | java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken` should do the same

Comment: It is same; instead of  replacing text with null in txt file it show null

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `Reporter.jar` by Runtime Process like below

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties Sales.generateToken");
```

I would suggest to directly add `Reporter.jar` in your project (like we do for DLL file in C#) and then call the related function from Jar.

```
Reporter Repo=new Reporter()
Repo.UserOrPasswordMEtho("Usrname","Password","Y");
```